# How does configurations based on XML work in Java?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, annotations

So I was comparing the coding styles, annotations and XML configuration. There I understood that compilers use annotation processors while processing annotations.
I would like to know what happens in case of XML configurations? How does compiler or jvm come into action while dealing with XML?

Thanks in advance

Comment: User who down vote the question, do share the reason , so that I can improve it. Simply down voting doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Spring loads various applicationContext-*.xml files on startup. 
Spring uses reflection to create these dependencies and so objects. 
When application starts up, it tries to load all the dependencies at loading time , eagerly by default  And so if any of the dependencies are missing it will start complaining about it. I hope that gives the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you be more clear at "Spring loads various applicationContext-*.xml files on startup". What does loading mean?

Comment: When the spring container starts up,  it tries to wire all the beans which are required to instantiate the objects used in the application.This all happens at the load time , means starting of the application when spring starts the configuration. And those dependencies or beans are searched in the application configuration.